# Python sklearn model.predict() gives me different results depending on the amount of data

Tags: machine-learning, python, xgboost, predict

I train my XGBoostClassifier().
If my testing set has:

```
0: 100 
1: 884
```

It attempts to predict 210 1's. Around 147 are wrong (False positives) and 63 1's correctly predicted (True positives).

Then I increase my testing sample:

```
0: 15,000
1: 884
```

It attempts to predict 56 1's. Around 40 are wrong (False positives) and 16 1's correctly predicted (True positives).

Am I missing something? some theory? some indication on how to use `model.predict(X_test)`?

Does it say somewhere - if you try to predict 10 items is gonna try harder than if you try to predict 10000 items? In what situation `model.predict(X_test)` would give me a different result for Joe Smith if his prediction is accompanied by 8000 more rows?

The code I use is the following:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
xgb = XGBClassifier(subsample=0.75,scale_post_weight=30,min_child_weight=1,max_depth=3,gamma=5,colsample_bytree=0.75)
model = xgb.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred_output = model.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred_output)

y_pred_output2 = model.predict(X_test2) #contains the same 884 1's plus 14500 more rows with 0's as the target value
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test2, y_pred_output2)
```

it produces two different matrices:

```
#Confusion matrix for y_test with 15000 0's and 884 1's
[[14864   136]
 [  837    47]]

#Confusion matrix for y_test with 500 0's and 884 1's
[[459  41]
 [681 203]]
```

Notice that the same 884 positive class items are being used across both attempts. Why would the true positives go down to 47 just because we now have more Negatives on the X_test?

Comment: are you running `.fit` again between the two?

Comment: No, I just edited the post to include the code. I fit the X_train, then do predict on the X_test.

Comment: I saw that code.  What I meant was, how are you getting the second test set, and what pieces of code are you running for that test set?

Comment: From an external file. test.csv. It has 15000 0's and 884 1's... When I limit the 0's to the first 500 of them, my true positives go higher! I'm like: "why would you care how many 0's there are?"

Comment: As already explained in the answer below, this should clearly **not** happen; but without the detailed way of your 2 test sets preparation, it is impossible to locate the exact issue - in all probability, this is a dataset preparation fault. These models actually perform the predictions one by one, so no single prediction "sees" (or cares about) the rest.

Comment: Have you used any Preprocessing step prior to fit/predict on the Datasets.

Comment: sure, and the line before was simply: test_df = pd.read_csv(test.csv). No preprocessing. I simply narrow down that file from 15000+884 and save it to X_test and then 500 (out of those 15000)+884(the very same 884 for X_test) and save it to X_test2. Apply to_numpy() and that's it. Logistic Regression seems to be more consistent but I understood, whatever is happening it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If XGBoostClassifier is fed the same input data over and over again it will yield the same results. There is no inherent randomness in this classifier that would different results for the same input. Additionally - there should be no difference in the result of an individual prediction if it's requested in a smaller batch versus a larger batch (again the result will be identical).

On the other hand - if you train XGBoost on different data their outputs will definitely be different. If you add new data to the underlying dataset & train with that - new & different patterns will emerge that XGBoost will try to take advantage of and the entire tree network will be fit very differently.

I suspect what you are observing is a bug in structuring your input data that you are then feeding to the .predict() method. If you share a sample of your code maybe we can drill-down on the issue.